# Will a Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 (international version) work reliably in the United States (comparable to a domestic phone)?

Tags: connection-issues, xiaomi, gsm

I'm buying a new phone, upgrading from an LG Q7+, and so far the best phone I've seen is the Xiaomi Redmi Note 9. The only con to this is that the Note 9 is only available in International version, and I live in the USA. I've heard that Metro by T-Mobile (my service provider) is good for international phones, but I don't know if it will be comparable to buying a domestic phone. That is, I don't want to get a really good phone but sacrifice all of my connection speed. If it's a little slower, I'm fine with it, but if it will be a major difference, I'll shop domestic.

One thing I've noticed is that, according to this site https://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?idPhone1=9206&idPhone2=10192 , the Note 9 actually has more 4G connectivity than my current Q7+ (11 bands compared to 9). Does this mean that it will be more reliable than my current phone, or does this mean nothing since it's international? (Note that I'm not very tech savvy. I know next to nothing about these complicated specs, so I don't actually understand the numbers)

The bottom line is, I want to buy a new phone, but I want to be sure that the new model I'm considering will have comparable connectivity speed to a domestic phone. I know that T-Mobile will support international phones, but I want to be sure that the support is good compared to their domestic support. If anyone reading this owns a Xiaomi in the US, I'd love to hear from you, but anyone who knows about this sort of topic would be extremely useful to hear from. Thank you to anyone who has read this far. I appreciate the help!

EDIT: I've found this site https://www.kimovil.com/en/frequency-checker/US/xiaomi-redmi-note-9 which suggests that it will work on US networks, but I have no idea what the numbers and technical terms mean. I'd like to know what exactly this says about the network reliability in the US. Thanks for putting up with my lack of tech knowledge!

Comment: A large number of supported frequency bands by the phone is good. But more important is what frequency bands are used by your mobile network provider (hence it has to support the "right" bands from your perspective). Every netwoprk provider uses different bands.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site after asking the question, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to try and leave a comment instead but my reputation is not high enough.

A useful site that breaks down frequency bands is

https://www.frequencycheck.com/compatibility/Jxq7inG/xiaomi-redmi-note-9-global-dual-sim-td-lte-64gb-xiaomi-merlin/united-states

This will show you the bands of each network in the US and will state whether the phone supports it or not.

I can see that it is stating that only 2 of 5 LTE bands are supported on T Mobile for this phone. So it is likely you may experience some issues with 4g mobile signal depending on the bands available at the location you are at.

[image]